# Where is the audit.log for Android 5?

Tags: android, selinux

On Android Kitkat, the SELinux audit log can be found here:

```
/data/misc/audit/audit.log
```

However, I cannot find this file on Android 5.0 (Nexus 5). Any idea where I can get the audit log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either kmsg or logcat; auditd was never officially merged (oem specific).

```
adb shell dmesg
```

or

```
adb logcat
```

Note that the logcat version is not formated in a way understandable by audit2allow but the dmesg output is.

The auditd code for Android (I am the author of) was never merged onto AOSP and thus mainline Android, it was rejected here:

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/51651/

Some OEMs picked the change back from either there or here:
https://bitbucket.org/seandroid/system-core/commits/branch/seandroid-4.3

See commits:
11389
e2cfa

The current implementation that routes the logs into logcat is under Change-Id: I421bcf33e7e670d596628b1b5c7c25536ce2d3fe (I could not post more than 2 links, so google for Android-Review and copy the change id starting with the capital I into the Gerrit search box)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
dmesg | grep 'avc: '
```

Comment: dmesg requires root permission on the phone. If not, can use `logcat | grep 'avc:'`